# Is there a way to clamp transform values to a set number?

Tags: transforms

When using a constraint like Limit Location, I can still move the digit transforms of the bone (in the transform window) even though the constraint is working and the object isn't going any further. I don't like how this feels though; I can drag the bone to infinity in the direction it is constrained, and the numbers still climb. It would take awhile to bring it back down (without simply tapping alt+g).

Is there a way to actually clamp the transform values themselves, so they never go over 1 or below -1?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ah! Nevermind, I figured it out. The little checkbox on the constraint, "For Transforms". How did I miss this.